# Google Charts - animating columns one by one

Tags: charts

I have a question about Google Graphs
I am using Bar Chart

So this is my data:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Year', 'mil. EUR'],
  ['2002', 6.2],
  ['2003', 7],
  ['2004', 9]
]);
```

They are animated, they slowly grow up, just like i want them to using this:

```
animation: {
  duration: 4000,
  easing: 'out'
},
```

However I would like them to grow one by one
So for example, column 1 grows, after 1 second column 2 grows and then after another second, column 3 grows

How can I achieve that?